# IF/ELSE-IF depending on quarter doesnt work for the last quarter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a statement that sums entries for every quarter of the year.

```
BEGIN
SET @mth = DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE())
IF @mth BETWEEN '1' AND '3'
-- SELECT-Statement
ELSE IF @mth BETWEEN '4' AND '6'
-- SELECT-Statement
ELSE IF @mth BETWEEN '7' AND '9'
-- SELECT-Statement
ELSE IF @mth BETWEEN '10' AND '12'
-- SELECT-Statement
END
```

Till yesterday the Select-Statement works fine and sums what i want, today it doenst work anymore. I tired the select statement separately and it works and gives me the correct result. I also tried to change "ELSE IF @mth BETWEEN '10' AND '12'" to "ELSE" in the line of '10' AND '12', no help. The debugger doesnt even stop if i set a breakpoint in front of the last select statement. Anyone an idea where the problem is?

Comment: Whats the value of @mth ?

Comment: Your code is working fine. I don't see any issue in this. What is not happening as per your expectation

Comment: @Sachin is right. The problem may lie in your `SELECT`s

Comment: Hi! @mth = 10. If i set the breakpoint at "IF mth BETWEEN '1' AND '3'" it stops there. If i comment the first IF out it stops at "ELSE IF mth BETWEEN '10' AND '12'". apprentely 1 matches 10 WHAT??? I dont understand that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that you probably Declared a `@mth` variable as `varchar` that can cause the issue. If you declared it as `int`, you will get your expected result.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @mth int
SET @mth = DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE())
IF @mth BETWEEN '1' AND '3'
print '1'
-- SELECT-Statement
ELSE IF @mth BETWEEN '4' AND '6'
print '2'
-- SELECT-Statement
ELSE IF @mth BETWEEN '7' AND '9'
print '3'
-- SELECT-Statement
ELSE IF @mth BETWEEN '10' AND '12'
print '4'
-- SELECT-Statement
END
```

Comment: If @mth is int now, perhaps BETWEEN clause must use ints too?

Answer (score 0):

it may be the reason that you have declare @mth as varchar,

define it as int

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could have solved it:

```
DECLARE @from datetime 
SET @from = dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, current_timestamp)/3*3, 0)
-- SELECT-Statement....
-- WHERE datefield >= @from
-- AND datefield < dateadd(month, 3, @from)
```